# Using Graphviz as a library with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, graphviz

I found a very simple example using graphviz as a library (and I also looked at the documentation having the same name) but I can't prevent the program from crashing as soon as it founds the line: gvc = gvContext();

Here is the program :

```
#include <gvc.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Agraph_t *g;
    Agnode_t *n, *m;
    Agedge_t *e;
    Agsym_t *a;
    GVC_t *gvc;
    printf("0\n");
    /* set up a graphviz context */
    gvc = gvContext();
    printf("1\n");
    /* parse command line args - minimally argv[0] sets layout engine */
    gvParseArgs(gvc, argc, argv);
    printf("2\n");
    /* Create a simple digraph */
    g = agopen("g", Agdirected, 0);
    n = agnode(g, "n", 1);
    m = agnode(g, "m", 1);
    e = agedge(g, n, m, 0, 1);
    /* Set an attribute - in this case one that affects the visible rendering */
    agsafeset(n, "color", "red", "");
    /* Compute a layout using layout engine from command line args */
    gvLayoutJobs(gvc, g);
    /* Write the graph according to -T and -o options */
    gvRenderJobs(gvc, g);
    /* Free layout data */
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    /* Free graph structures */
    agclose(g);
    /* close output file, free context, and return number of errors */
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```

And finally the compilation and execution line (I intend to have portable code in the future):

gcc -Wall dot2.c -o dot -L/usr/lib -lcgraph -lgvc -lgraph -I /home/svin/CPP/graphviz-2.38.0/lib/gvc -I /home/svin/CPP/graphviz-2.38.0/lib/common/ -I /home/svin/CPP/graphviz-2.38.0/lib/pathplan/ -I /home/svin/CPP/graphviz-2.38.0/lib/cgraph/ -I /home/svin/CPP/graphviz-2.38.0/lib/cdt/

./dot -Tgif -o abc.gif

Any idea why I get a seg fault and a core dumped ?
Thanks !

Comment: You seem to be using library files installed in /usr/lib, (and -L/usr/lib is unnecessary, by the way), and header files from your own graphviz build. Perhaps the headers and the libraries are not compatible.

Comment: Yes, the program works if linked with the lib corresponding to the used header.

Comment: However the program now complains when I run : "./dot" it says "There is no layout engine support for dot". As far I as understand the associated documentation it should work in this case...